# Primitive conversions code | Help needed to understand

Tags: java

Please help me to understand how following code is working?

```java
int i = (byte) +(char) -(int) +(long) -1;
```

Comment: What is the problem? What behavior you find strange?

Comment: Oleg, he does not find the behavior strange, he wants to understand how it works. from -1 to 1.

Comment: @Skynet Then why his title contains "strange behavior"?

Comment: He might be a newbie here, I just tried to explain his intent as I understand it.

Comment: I just want to understand how following code is parsed by JVM and how I receive following result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Expanded code

```
final long longValue = +(long) -1;
final int intValue = -(int) longValue;
final int charValue = +(char) intValue;
final int byteValue = (byte) charValue;
System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s%n", longValue, intValue, charValue, byteValue);
```

Output:

```
-1 1 1 1
```

## Explanation

- The long value is the same -1 as before, but as a long, because + by iteself does nothing

  - After value: `-1`
- The int value is equal to 1, as it inverts the -1

  - After value: `1`
- The char value keeps this value, but converts to a char

  - After value: `1`
- The byte value keeps this value, but converts to a byte

  - After value: `1`

So the end result is 1